# Why does local ArcGIS API for JavaScript over https trigger info request over http?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I got the esri js api 3.14 deployed on a server and an application that is reachable over https.

Now I got a proxy script that delivers the map requests.

When you look at the requests of the page you can see that there is ONE request (an info request to the rest interace) that goes directly to the internalServer.

The Chrome Browser says: 
[image]

Firefox says:

[image]

I added the proxy script rule like this:

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
                urlPrefix: "http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest/services/utjsc_de/Grundkarte",
                proxyUrl: "ESRI_proxy.jsp"
            });
```

Is it possible to tell the js-api to use the proxy script for this "initial" info request?

Comment: This is the URL to the application https://demo.baral.de/EsriProxyTest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to share your services in applications that utilize HTTPS, then you are far better off configuring ArcGIS Server to support it than relying on a proxy to attempt to '[fake it](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/issues/218#issuecomment-78616545)'.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/03/11/sharing-web-gis-services-always-enable-tls/

that being said, the info request is a [check](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/new_v30.html) for [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) support, so if you know that the server already supports CORS (or that you won't need it to), you can skip sending the request by calling

```
esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("[server.domain]");
```

example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/bypass.html).

Comment: He's not trying to 'fake' HTTPS, he's trying to get the API to use his proxy for that URL. It's an internal server anyway (the server `srvutdemo102` isn't accessible from the interweb) so he has to do something along those lines.

Comment: he is 100% faking https.  this is why his browser is complaining about mixed content.  seperately, you are correct that his technique is exposing a server thats otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: If the proxy call worked (which is his actual question) it would be calling it over HTTPS, because the proxy's on the same server. Therefore there's no 'faking' HTTPS or CORS issues.

Comment: This is a real life scenario. The application "runs" in a **DMZ** and the ArcGIS Server and the Databases are in the **LAN**. The ArcGIS Server will never be reachable directly from www. Btw it´s way to expensive to place a second ArcGIS Server in the DMZ :)

Comment: Johns answer ist correct ! I set `esriConfig.defaults.io.corsDetection=false;` to disable the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy rule specifies the URL **prefix**

`http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest/services/utjsc_de/Grundkarte`

but in my Chrome dev tools Network tab the first request is to

`http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest/info?f=json`

...which doesn't match the prefix. If you modify your proxy role URL to `http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest` I think you will have a lot more success.

Comment: Sorry to say: Its the same... I updated the example page.

Comment: I think @JohnGravois and I are both correct, just coming from different angles. With the above changes to the proxy rule I can see lots of calls to `https://demo.baral.de/EsriProxyTest/ESRI_proxy.jsp?http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest/services/utjsc_de/Grundkarte/MapServer/tile/4/76472/81098`, which is the proxy page functioning correctly.

Comment: However the direct call to `http://srvutdemo102/arcgis/rest/info?f=json` is made (and throws the error in Chrome) regardless of proxy settings unless you turn CORS detection off. Of course even if Chrome didn't block it, the call would fail because it's not in your DMZ....